# Erro cannot open tty-output Linux

Tags: linux, boot

Eu tenho instalado uma imagem paravirtualiada do Debian8 no XenServer, e estou adicionando um script para criar um template dessa vm. Adicionei na inicialização o script com o comando "systemctl enable script". No scritp eu utilizo o dialog que já está instalado.

Quando eu converto a vm para template e crio uma nova vm, no log syslog me aparece o seguinte erro como se o script tivesse iniciando no momento errado do boot:

```
initial-conf[407]: Error opening terminal: unknown.
initial-conf[407]: cannot open tty-output
initial-conf[407]: Error opening terminal: unknown.
```